# Tell Excel Which Sheet to Pull Data From in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am writing a VB.Net program to pull information from an Excel sheet and display it on my keyboard's LCD panel. However, I've run into some trouble. I managed to get it to display on the LCD, and read the data from Excel.

However, it isn't pulling from the worksheet that I want. It pulls from the middle worksheet in the book, and this is a large, multi-megabyte book that has numerous sheets. My code is as follows.

```
Dim Excel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Dim intraday As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
Dim iSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
Dim t As String

Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\excelworkbook.xlsm")
iSheet = Excel.Workbooks(1).Worksheets(9)
t = Excel.Cells(11, 1).Value.ToString
```

Comment: iSheet = Excel.Workbooks(1).Worksheets(9) --> change to .Worksheets(n) where n is your desired worksheet

Comment: This has no effect. I have changed this to numerous values, and there is no change.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code.

```
Dim Excel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Dim intraday As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
Dim iSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
Dim t As String

Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
intraday=Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\excelworkbook.xlsm")
iSheet = intraday.Worksheets(n)
t = Excel.Cells(11, 1).Value.ToString
```

where n is the desired worksheet.

Comment: This throws a "System.NullReference Exception".